# Баг 2X iPad iOS 6.1

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Программа написана под iPhone, работает от iOS 4.3 ее можно запустить и на iPad в оконном режиме и тут начинается веселье. На всех прошивках, кроме iOS 6 программа работает нормально. На iOS 6 она не реагирует на тачи, пока не нажмешь кнопку х2 (растягивание на весь экран), после чего она работает абсолютно корректно (Даже если потом нажать на x1)

Кто-то сталкивался с подобным ?

Comment: Думаю, стоит оформить ваше решение как ответ в форме снизу и принять его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зайтиде в Xcode project -> Targets -> Summary, Опуститесь до 'Status Bar', поставьте галочку в 'Visibility' Все, работает! Дальше надо запустить 'Status Bar' из кода в 'AppDelegate'

> [application setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];